# Cassandra 3.4 Java LIKE operator

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

Cassandra 3.4 now offers the LIKE operator by way of a custom index.

It works fine in my test example using cqlsh with something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE indexed_column LIKE '%VALU%'`. I've set up an index and it all functions perfectly.

How do I do this in the Java Driver (I'm using version 3.0.2) with dynamic values? My query works using the QueryBuilder and using PreparedStatements when using a literal value like so (PS example but QueryBuilder works with literal values also):

```
PreparedStatement ps = PreparedStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE indexed_column LIKE '%VALU%'");
```

But not if I want to use ? to bind a value (e.g. bind '%VAL%') in either the QueryBuilder or using PreparedStatements. E.g.

```
PreparedStatement ps = PreparedStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE indexed_column LIKE ?");
BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(ps);
cassandraSession.execute(boundStatement.bind('%VAL%');
```

I get the following error:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:53 mismatched input '?' expecting STRING_LITERAL (...test.table WHERE indexed_column LIKE [?];)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in 3.4 that was fixed in C* 3.6 via [CASSANDRA-11456](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11456) in that you couldn't provide a bind marker (?) for a value on the LIKE operator.  If you upgrade to Cassandra 3.6 this should work.